# How can i prevent function .fadein() in jQuery from sending user to top of the page?

Tags: jquery, joomla, fadein, page-jump

I have a menu where i basically click and hide current p and fadein the corresponding button text. Thing is, it makes my page literally jump to the top.

Here is the html for menu:

```
<li class="sub"><a href="#" class="sub_ha1"> 
   › Instalação/Configuração de Componentes</a>
</li>
```

Here is the html for corresponding text

:

```
<div id="sub_ha1" class="text" style="display:block;">
  <img src="../images/serv/ha1.jpg" alt="">
  <h1> Instalação/Configuração de Componentes - 35€ </h1>

  <p>Chamamos de hardware a todos os componentes ..... </p>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#navigation a.sub_ha1").click(function () {
$(".text").hide();
$("#sub_ha1").fadeIn();
return false;
});
```

What i want, is a way to prevent it because it just makes it annoying after getting through a few menus.

Thanks

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/M2AE6/
if you click about or contact menus after clicking 1st or 2nd menu item you'll see what is happening.

Comment: Does it jump as soon as the link is clicked, or after the fadeIn is finished?

Comment: see this  http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/uruJJ/5/

Comment: can you post the CSS?

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma as soon as the link is clicked.

Comment: @MohammadAdil it still has the same behaviour.

Comment: @DaveB for menu text or both ?

Comment: Both if possible (in a JSFiddle would be ideal), could be a pageflow issue

Comment: @DaveB done ty, i'll be gone for a while tho.

Comment: what if you use `function() { $(".text").not($("#sub_ha1").fadeIn()).hide(); return false; }` so that `#sub_ha1` gets shown (initially with opacity 0) before the other `.text` are hidden?

Comment: @tcovo I believe that's the issue as well.

Comment: set container heights to match tallest. Is jumping due to no scroll height when content doesn't overflow window height

Comment: @tcovo So i replace my function with yours for each different menu item ? and change the $("#sub_ha1") for each ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tcovo said in a comment to the main question `what if you use function() { $(".text").not($("#sub_ha1").fadeIn()).hide(); return false; } so that #sub_ha1 gets shown (initially with opacity 0) before the other .text are hidden? – tcovo` , this actually worked out pretty great except for when total text height was smaller than menu. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your links href.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your code seems right, you can try this one:

```
$("#navigation a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // <----stop it here
   $(".text").hide();
   $("#"+this.className).fadeIn(); // <--this will get you the specific div you want to fade In.
   // $("[id='"+this.className + "']").fadeIn();// <---another way to do it
});
```

Comment: doesn't return false execute both e.preventDefault(); and e.stopPropagation ?

Comment: @BrunoCharters Yes it does.